# How can I make nginx wait longer before returning 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: nginx

I'm using docker-compose for development with Django, and have one container running Django's development server, and another container running nginx that proxy's requests to that container.

When code changes, the development server automatically restarts. This can sometimes take a few seconds.  When I refresh the page, it immediately goes to 502 Bad Gateway while the server is restarting. Is there a timeout setting in nginx that will wait for the gateway to become available? Otherwise I have to sit there and refresh repeatedly until it loads.

I currently have `proxy_read_timeout` set to 300s.

Comment: Have you tried to use a `upstream` definition and `slow_start=10s`? https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html. Not a 100% sure if this will do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like `slow_start` is only available in the enterprise/commercial version of Nginx.